# AC form for a FET circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, analog

Can someone help me with getting the AC form of this MOSFET circuit? I am having trouble understanding why in class they took Q1 and Q2 out of the AC form:

[image]

The AC form they showed us in class (the FET you see here is Q3):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Given the above, all you are left with is Q3 being part of the small signal AC analysis. The two capacitors are shorted because, their dominant use is to prevent DC levels being affected by external inputs and outputs hence, in small signal AC analysis, we can ignore and short them out.

Comment: @RanGreidi [Take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how to give thanks the "stack-exchange" way !!

Comment: can you help me understand it better? why can they be ignored? Q1 is saturated for all posibble conditions becouse Vds=Vgs doesnt that mean that it cant be ignored?  Im trying to understand is exactly why Q1 Q2 and Q3 is used to set the bais votlage. as I understand Q1 and Q2 are used as a current mirror. and Q4 has the same source current as Q3 due to the 10K resistors. that is apply to both small signal AC and DC. which means the current at the source of Q2 has to be the same as the current at the source of Q3. thus both of them cancle the current the the 10K resistor at the junction of V1

Comment: Q2's drain is a very high impedance current source and therefore, it only has an effect at DC and extremely high frequencies. Q4 is independent of Q2 and Q4 drives Q1 and Q2 therefore, only Q3 needs to be considered for small signal AC analysis.